# Calculation involving repeated items in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table with a composite primary key on EID (event ID) and start_time. I have another column called attending.

Users make their events more popular by reusing the event ID and changing the date, however, I create a new line in the database in this instance.

I would like to create a 4th column, actual_attending which is equal to the attending value minus the previous event's attending value. If their is no previous ID, the column can be null. How can I calculate this via update.

Here is a sqlfiddle as an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43f2c5

Comment: consider providing a sqlfiddle

Comment: now provided, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
update event e1
set e1.actual_attending = (select e1.attending - e2.attending
                           from event e2
                           where e2.eid(+) = e1.previous_eid
                          )
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') = e1.previous_eid
                          )' at line 4

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
     , a.attending-b.attending new_actual_attending
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , COUNT(*) rank
         FROM event x
         JOIN event y
           ON y.eid = x.eid
          AND y.start_time <= x.start_time
        GROUP
           BY eid, start_time
     ) a
  LEFT
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , COUNT(*) rank
         FROM event x
         JOIN event y
           ON y.eid = x.eid
          AND y.start_time <= x.start_time
        GROUP
           BY eid, start_time
     ) b
    ON b.eid = a.eid
   AND b.rank = a.rank - 1;

   +-----+------------+-----------+------------------+------+----------------------+
   | eid | start_time | attending | actual_attending | rank | new_actual_attending |
   +-----+------------+-----------+------------------+------+----------------------+
   |   1 | 2013-06-08 |        29 |             NULL |    1 |                 NULL |
   |   2 | 2013-06-09 |        72 |             NULL |    1 |                 NULL |
   |   2 | 2013-06-16 |       104 |             NULL |    2 |                   32 |
   |   3 | 2013-06-07 |       224 |             NULL |    1 |                 NULL |
   |   3 | 2013-06-14 |       222 |             NULL |    2 |                   -2 |
   +-----+------------+-----------+------------------+------+----------------------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43f2c5/2